# Export button position changes in ie 11 for high charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

```
exporting: {
                enabled: true,
                buttons: {
                    contextButton: {
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0

                    }
                }
            },
```

Comment: Well in the Chrome / IE looks like the same, can you replicate entire chart, add information about IE11 revision and attach any screenshots ?

Answer (score 0):

try the follwoing.

```
   exporting: {
                enabled: true
   }

   navigation: {
                buttonOptions: {
                    align: 'right', 
                    verticalAlign: 'top', 
                     x: 0, 
                     y: 0
                }
            }
```